# display jquery yearly calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display jquery yearly calendar as shown in image.

[image]

now I displayed only monthly calendar [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/VBGKU/748/)

```js
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p>Date:
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add

`numberOfMonths: [3, 4]` in you jquery

**[FIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/VBGKU/750/)**

you can edit the [Row,Column] as per your need

Comment: Did you check how it will get displayed - https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VBGKU/749/

Answer (score 2):

Use this script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: [3,4]
    });
});
```

Thanks
Amit